# How unstable is Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I just wanted to know how unstable is flex4 when compared to flex3?
Which is preferred most flex3 or flex4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex 4 is typically more preferred because of its skinning capabilities and more mature components.

Considering [the Flex 4.5 SDK was released recently](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/introducing-flex45sdk.html), I wouldn't consider Flex 4 unstable at all. If you're still concerned about the stability of the 4.5 SDK because it was released recently, you can always develop against 4.0 or 4.1.

If you want to compare the Flex 3 and Flex 4 components side by side, I would recommend [Tour de Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html). It's get good examples of each component for both Flex 3 and Flex 4.

Answer (score 3):

That's kind of a leading question that assumes flex 4 *is* unstable?  Flex 4 got a stable release a year ago; it's production-ready.